# Liferay robots.txt new line disappearing

Tags: seo, liferay, web.xml, robots.txt

I am trying to exclude all my liferay testing environment from search engines.
The new line is disappearing and \r\n or \n as separators are not working either.

This is my robots file:

```
User-agent: *
Disallow: /
```

This is my web.xml snippet:

```
<filter>
      <filter-name>RobotKiller</filter-name>
      <filter-class>com.robot.kill.KillARobot</filter-class>
</filter>

<filter-mapping>
      <filter-name>RobotKiller</filter-name>
      <url-pattern>/robots.txt</url-pattern>
</filter-mapping>
```

domain/robots.txt:

```
User-agent: *Disallow: /
```

Comment: Not sure about your newline problem, but your robots.txt disallow is incorrect.  It should be `Disallow: /` do prevent all crawling.

Comment: You are right, I written it incorrectly in this question. Edited the question

Comment: I just use the Liferay web interface.  Go to Site Settings -> Robots and put in the two lines. I don't adjust any web.xml text to do this. Is this not working for you?

Comment: Is it available in 6.0.6 because I can't seem to find it? Thanks

Answer (score 2):

I think I know what the problem is.  The [Content-Type HTTP header](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec14.html#sec14.17) is set incorrectly on this file.  You have the content type set to `text/html` when it should be set to `text/plain`.

When you view the file in your browser, it interprets it is HTML which treats new lines as spaces.  You should be able to use your browser's view source feature to see it formatted correctly.

The robots.txt file may work for the search bots, even with an incorrect Content-Type header, but it would be better not to take any chances.

Comment: I don't think that's the problem, I used wget to get the file and opened it with nano and vi and it loses the new line as well.
Also when I do view page source this is what I get:
      User-agent: *Disallow: /
However, can you still guide me how to fix the HTTP header?

Comment: That may not be the problem then.  You can see what the content-type header actually is from the command line with `curl`: `curl -D - 'http://example.com/robots.txt' | grep -i content-type`